# Invalid JSON with jquery, ajax and TYPO3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, typo3

I get the following error message when sending an ajax request:

```
Invalid JSON: {"html":"","jobNum":"0"}<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN"><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>
```

So json_encode appends a piece of html to the object. This is really annoying because a few minutes ago everything was working fine until I cleared all caches and temporary files in TYPO3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED.
The problem was that I installed and configured "tidy" for cleaning up my HTML code on the frontend.

Comment: We have 2022 now. After all those years this answer pointed me into the right direction. Had a simular problem and a new introduced bug in lochmueller/sourceopt extension was the reason. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably returning this from you a custom extension/plugin I assume?

Probably what is happening is that Typo3 is rendering a page via Typoscript. This happens after all plugins on that page have been called.

Now if you have only one plugin that needs to be called on that page, and it needs to output json, then the following solution is the easiest:

```
exit(json_encode(array('html'=> '', 'jobNum' => '0')));
```

Another way would be to have a seperate Typoscript template on the page that outputs this plugin. I can help you with that as well if you'd like.

Comment: This will work. Personnaly, prefer syntax : print (json_encode(array('html'=> '', 'jobNum' => '0'))); exit();

Comment: Thanks @Fedir. Indeed print() will also work, and a bit more readable.

Comment: @booman: Ooh.. interesting to see it was 'tidy' that messed things up hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response contains not only the (valid JSON), but a primitive basic HTML base frame. Find out which line of code outputs

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>
```

and disable/remove that line in your JSON output code.

Comment: `return json_encode(array('html'=> '', 'jobNum' => '0'));`

This is the return statement. There is nothing more.

Comment: @booman That's the line that returns the JSON string. I'm afraid you'll have to look into other functions and files, too, to find the offending output line. A good candidate is the function that *calls* the one that's returning JSON.

Comment: But as you can see, I don't use any variables in this statement. There is just an array with 2 fields containing an empty string and a zero.

Comment: @booman Sorry, I don't know to phrase it any more clear: The problem is **not** in the function returning the JSON, but in one of the functions *calling* that function.

Comment: This is the whole class and the function main() is called in which is just one return statement.

`<?php

if (!(TYPO3_REQUESTTYPE & TYPO3_REQUESTTYPE_FE)) {
 die ();
}

class ajax_getJobs {

 public function main() {
  return json_encode(array('html'=> 'test', 'jobNum' => '0'));
 }

}

echo ajax_getJobs::main();

?>`

Comment: @booman Try calling `exit` after the `echo`, like `echo ajax_getJobs::main(); exit();`. Notice that this is *still* not the place where the HTML is outputted, you'll have to look *even further* up in the stack for that.